# Updating a table based on similar table with same structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have test table(1) with following values

| ID | date | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-20 | 12 | 33 | 23 | 12 |
| 2 | 2021-10-20 | 43 | 12 | 22 | 56 |
| 1 | 2021-10-21 | 12 | 21 | 24 | 44 |
| 1 | 2021-10-22 | 34 | 25 | 11 | 31 |
| 1 | 2021-10-23 | 33 | 24 | 34 | 41 |

Yet I have an update of this table called table(2) :

| ID | date | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-20 | 12 | 33 | 23 | 12 |
| 2 | 2021-10-20 | 43 | 12 | 22 | 56 |
| 1 | 2021-10-21 | 12 | 21 | 24 | 44 |
| 1 | 2021-10-22 | 34 | 25 | 11 | 31 |
| 1 | 2021-10-23 | 33 | 24 | 34 | 41 |
| 1 | 2021-10-24 | 35 | 23 | 12 | 43 |
| 1 | 2021-10-25 | 36 | 17 | 16 | 34 |
| 1 | 2021-10-26 | 37 | 18 | 15 | 26 |
| 2 | 2021-10-21 | 38 | 19 | 19 | 36 |
| 2 | 2021-10-22 | 29 | 12 | 17 | 37 |

As you can see table(2) is similar table(1) but it has new values with new dates for each ID.
How should I use update command to update table1 based on new values of table2

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Why do you have such similar tables?

Comment: I want to update a table based on new values of it

Comment: Why do you copy data between to similar tables?

Comment: Do I copy data? I want to use update command in order to update my table, table 1 have older records but table 2 has new records

Comment: Keep all data in the same table.

Comment: I don't access to Table2 , it is just a readable table,and table2 updates by time I have to update table1 and do process of data cleaning of table2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql the fastest way to do so via a merge function, it will add the new rows to the table1 that are existing in table2 and not in table1.

```
merge into table1 t1
using table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.date = t2.date
when not matched then 
insert (t1.id, t1.date, t1.value1, t1.value2 , t1.value3, t1.value4)
values (t2.id, t2.date, t2.value1, t2.value2 , t2.value3, t2.value4)
```

Comment: thanks for your code.can you provide me with update version of your code? I mean by using update command.

Comment: @RF1991 please have a go yourself and post when stuck! The official docs themselves show how to use the update statement.

Comment: yet it didn't worked for me following error.    The insert column list used in the MERGE statement cannot contain multi-part identifiers. Use single part identifiers instead.

Comment: The insert column list used in the MERGE statement cannot contain multi-part identifiers. Use single part identifiers instead.

Comment: thanks it worked for me with some modifications

Comment: Awesome, was glad to help

Comment: to remove error , I delete alias of table 1 and I used ;

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you have multiple records for each id in table2 and you want the values against the latest row based on the data to be updated to table1. in such a case, you can try with a `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` function, just like this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC),
        id,
        date,
        val1,
        val2,
        val3
        FROM Table2
)
UPDATE T1
    SET
        Val1 = T2.Val1
        Val2 = T2.Val2
    FROM Table1 T1  
        INNER JOIN CTE T2
            ON T1.id = T2.id
        WHERE T2.RN = 1
```

Comment: this code update values not update table, I want to update my table based on new values of another table.

Comment: @RF1991 Are you looking for a query to update the Table structure based on another? then I'm afraid it's not possible