# Insert if not exist, delete if the role changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table UserRole:

```
|User|Role|
|----|----|
|A   |  X |
|B   |  Y |
|C   |  Z |
|D   |  W |
```

Now a new table comes in say UserRoleNew:

```
|User|Role|
|----|----|
|A   |   X|
|A   |   W|
|B   |   Z|
|C   |   Z|
|F   |   X|
```

Based on UserRoleNew I need to modify UserRole table following these rules:

-> If the role for a user changed then the existing role should be deleted and new role should be inserted.

-> If there is a new user then the user and role should be inserted

-> If there is no information about an existing user in the UserRoleNew then this user and his role should be retained.

-> One user can have multiple roles

So the new UserRole table should look like this:

```
|User|Role|
|----|----|
|A   |   X|
|A   |   W|
|B   |   Z|
|C   |   Z|
|D   |   W|
|F   |   X|
```

Edit-> Table definition of UserRole is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRole]( 
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [Pk_UserRole] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,  
    [ApplicationUserId] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [UserRoleId] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Yes a user can have more than one role. Just edited the post

Comment: Do you have a compound key on user/role? Please publish table definitions so we can see what we are dealing with.

Comment: The use of square brackets, dbo and identity indicates this is sqlserver rather than mysql and I have changed the tags accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749565/updating-a-table-based-on-similar-table-with-same-structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MERGE](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/) for this.

But the missing users need to be included in the source query.
Since the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE` is kinda brutal.

> ```
> --
> -- Merge UserRoleNew into UserRole, including the missing users
> --
> MERGE INTO UserRole tgt
> USING (
>   SELECT ApplicationUserId, UserRoleId
>   FROM UserRoleNew
>   
>   UNION ALL
>   
>   SELECT ApplicationUserId, UserRoleId
>   FROM UserRole t
>   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
>     SELECT 1
>     FROM UserRoleNew t2
>     WHERE t2.ApplicationUserId = t.ApplicationUserId
>   )
> ) src 
>   ON (src.ApplicationUserId = tgt.ApplicationUserId
>  AND src.UserRoleId = tgt.UserRoleId)
> WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
>     INSERT (ApplicationUserId, UserRoleId) 
>     VALUES (src.ApplicationUserId, src.UserRoleId)
> WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ApplicationUserName, UserRoleName
> FROM UserRole AS ur
> LEFT JOIN ApplicationUsers AS usr
>   ON usr.ApplicationUserId = ur.ApplicationUserId
> LEFT JOIN UserRoleNames role 
>   ON role.UserRoleId = ur.UserRoleId
> ORDER BY ApplicationUserName, UserRoleName;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ApplicationUserName | UserRoleName
> :------------------ | :-----------
> A                   | W           
> A                   | X           
> B                   | Z           
> C                   | Z           
> D                   | W           
> F                   | X
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83ad34b914c4206e100a9d1e236e03f7)*